# Understanding the error "Element legend not allowed as child of element div in this context."

Tags: html, validation

Below is my HTML markup. I use Bootstrap, and followed many of their examples. Nevertheless, when validation with the W3C HTML validator, I get a lot of errors of the type:

```
"Element legend not allowed as child of element div in this context."
```

I do not understand this error message. What does it mean? How should I change my HTML?

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- Bootstrap customisations:
    No responsiveness
    @navbarBackground: #568FB6
    @navbarBackgroundHighlight: lighten(#568FB6, 12%)
-->

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
    <title>DeepFlow</title>

    <link href='./img/favicon.ico' rel='icon'>

    <link href='./css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='./css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='./css/global.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='./css/login.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='./css/custom.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script src='./RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js'></script>
    <script src='./RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.annotate.js'></script>
    <script src='./RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.effects.js'></script>
    <script src='./RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js'></script>
    <script src='./RGraph/libraries/RGraph.gauge.js'></script>
    <script src='./RGraph/libraries/RGraph.line.js'></script>

    <script src='./js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script>jQuery.fx.speeds._default = 800;</script>
    <script src='./js/underscore.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/bootstrap.js'></script>

    <script src='./js/ajax.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/navbar.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/login.js'></script>

    <script src='./js/users.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/editUser.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/addUser.js'></script>

    <script src='./js/statistics.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/protocols.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/export.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/tuple.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/network.js'></script>
</head>

<div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top' style='display:none'>
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='brand'>DeepFlow</div>
            <div id='navbar-container'>
                <ul class='nav panes-nav'>
                    <li id='statistics-label'><a>Statistics</a></li>
                    <li id='protocols-label'><a>Protocols</a></li>
                    <li id='tuples-label'><a>Tuples</a></li>
                    <li id='exports-label'><a>Exports</a></li>
                    <li id='users-label'><a>Users</a></li>
                    <li id='network-label'><a>Network</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class='nav pull-right'>
                    <li id='sign-out'><a>Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='wrap'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='alert alert-error' style='display:none'>
            <span id='error-message'></span>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>
        </div>

        <div class='hero-unit' id='login-unit'>
            <h2>Welcome to DeepFlow</h2>
            <p>Please log in</p>
            <center id='login-box' class='pull-right control-group'>
                <div class='clearfix'>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Username' id='login-username'/>
                </div>
                <div class='clearfix'>
                    <input type='password' placeholder='Password' id='login-password'/>
                </div>
                <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' id='login-button'>Log in</button>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class='row pane' id='statistics-pane' style='display:none'>
            <legend>Network</legend>

            <div class='form-horizontal well'>
                <div class='offset1'>
                    <div class='control-group statistics-group'>
                        <label class='control-label graph-label'>
                            <div>Packets per second</div>
                            <p class='live-statistic' data-ending='' data-precision='0'></p>
                        </label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <canvas id='pps_graph' width='500' height='100'>[No canvas support]</canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='control-group statistics-group'>
                        <label class='control-label graph-label'>
                            <div>Throughput</div>
                            <p class='live-statistic' data-ending='&nbsp;kB/s' data-precision='0'></p>
                        </label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <canvas id='throughput_graph' width='500' height='100'>[No canvas support]</canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='statistics-group'>
                        <label class='control-label graph-label'id='packets-dropped-group'>
                            <div>Packets dropped</div>
                            <p class='live-statistic' data-ending='' data-precision='0'></p>
                        </label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <canvas id='packets_dropped_graph' width='500' height='100'>[No canvas support]</canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <legend>System</legend>
            <div class='form-horizontal well'>
                <div class='offset1'>
                    <div class='control-group statistics-group'>
                        <label class='control-label graph-label'>
                            <div>CPU usage</div>
                            <p class='live-statistic' data-ending='&nbsp;%' data-precision='2'></p>
                        </label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <canvas id='cpu_graph' width='500' height='100'>[No canvas support]</canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='statistics-group'>
                        <label class='control-label graph-label'>
                            <div>Memory usage</div>
                            <p class='live-statistic' data-ending='&nbsp;k' data-precision='0'></p>
                        </label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <canvas id='memory_graph' width='500' height='100'>[No canvas support]</canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row pane' id='protocols-pane' style='display:none'>
            <legend>Protocol list</legend>
            <table class='table table-hover table-condensed offset3' id='protocol-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Protocol</th>
                        <th id='protocol-status-column'></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id='protocol-rows'>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class='row pane' id='tuples-pane' style='display:none'>
            <legend>List of tuples</legend>
            <table class='table table-hover offset3' id='tuple-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th id='tuples-status-column'></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id='tuples-rows'>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class='row pane' id='exports-pane' style='display:none'>
            <legend>Configure export destinations</legend>
            <table class='table table-hover' id='exports-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>URL</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>Port</th>
                        <th>Format</th>
                        <th id='exports-edit-column'></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id='exports-rows'>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class='modal hide fade' id='edit-export-modal'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <span type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                    <h3>Edit export <code id='edit-export-old'></code></h3>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                    <form class='form-horizontal'>
                        <div class='control-group'>
                            <label class='control-label'>New IP</label>
                            <div class='controls'>
                                <input type='text' id='edit-export-ip' placeholder='IP'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='control-group'>
                            <label class='control-label'>New port</label>
                            <div class='controls'>
                                <input type='text' id='edit-export-port' placeholder='Port'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label class='control-label'>New format</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='text' id='edit-export-format' placeholder='Format'/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                    <span class='btn' id='edit-export-close'>Close</span>
                    <span class='btn btn-primary' id='edit-export-save'>Save changes</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row pane' id='users-pane' style='display:none'>
            <div class='span6'>
                <legend>List of users</legend>
                <table class='table table-hover' id='users-table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User</th>
                            <th>Rights</th>
                            <th id='users-edit-column'></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id='user-rows'>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id='new-user-box' class='span6'>
                <legend>Add a new user</legend>
                <form class='form-horizontal well'>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Username</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='text' class='username' id='new-user-username' placeholder='Username'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Password</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='password' class='password' id='new-user-password' placeholder='Password'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Rights</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons-radio' id='new-user-rights'/>
                                <span class='btn'>Administrator</span>
                                <span class='btn' id='new-user-operator'>Operator</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='controls'>
                        <span class='btn btn-primary' id='new-user-button'>Add new user</span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class='modal hide fade' id='edit-user-modal'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <span class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                    <h3>Edit user <code id='edit-user-old-username'></code></h3>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                    <form class='form-horizontal'>
                        <div class='control-group'>
                            <label class='control-label'>New username</label>
                            <div class='controls'>
                                <input type='text' class='username' id='edit-user-username' placeholder='(Leave unchanged)'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='control-group'>
                            <label class='control-label'>New password</label>
                            <div class='controls'>
                                <input type='password' class='password' id='edit-user-password' placeholder='(Leave unchanged)'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label class='control-label'>New rights</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons-radio' id='edit-user-rights'>
                                <span class='btn'>Administrator</span>
                                <span class='btn'>Operator</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                    <span class='btn btn-danger pull-left' data-action='remove'><i class='icon-trash'></i> Remove</span>
                    <span class='btn' data-action='close'>Close</span>
                    <span class='btn btn-primary' data-action='save'>Save changes</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='pane' id='network-pane' style='display:none'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='alert alert-info' style='display:none'>
                    Use this pane to configure the server network. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </div>
                <form class='span6 form-horizontal'>
                    <legend>Basic configurations</legend>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>IP address</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='text' id='network-ip' placeholder='IP address'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Subnet mask</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='text' id='network-mask' placeholder='Subnet mask'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Default gateway</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='text' id='network-gateway' placeholder='Default gateway'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form class='span6 form-horizontal'>
                    <legend>Optional fields</legend>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>DNS hostname</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='text' id='network-dns' placeholder='DNS hostname'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label class='control-label'>NTP server hostname</label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <input type='text' id='network-ntp' placeholder='NTP server hostname'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <center>
                <span class='btn btn-large btn-primary' id='network-save'>Save and reboot server now</span>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id='push'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='footer'>
    <div class='container'>
        <span class='muted credit'>&copy; Copyright 2013 Qosmos SA. All rights reserved.</span>
        <img id='logo' src='./img/logo_grey.png' alt='logo'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more details you add (ids, names, labels, etc.) the harder the markup is to read quickly, but the following illustrates the intent of a `legend` element. It's intended to identify groups of inputs that relate to one another. That group is then wrapped in a `fieldset`.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Like Using Fieldsets?</legend>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Name</legend>
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="text" name="lname">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/legend

(note: the code above is solely to highlight the use of legends.)

Answer (score 4):

`<legend>` tags belong directly underneath `<fieldset>` tags.

See [w3c](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/legend)

Answer (score 1):

that is bug in validator ,

i have

```
<div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Something</legend>
.......
</fieldset>
</div>
```

and get same bug

see 
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-wg-issue-tracking/2012Jan/0008.html